# Please help me interpret function

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, documentation

I was given the task of documenting an application that has no comments. However, I have been unable to understand the following function.

```
private uint GetVersionHash(int encver, int realver)
{
    int EncryptedVersionNumber = encver;
    int VersionNumber = realver;
    int VersionHash = 0;
    int DecryptedVersionNumber = 0;
    string VersionNumberStr;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, l = 0;

    VersionNumberStr = VersionNumber.ToString();

    l = VersionNumberStr.Length;

    // I am specifically struggling with the purpose and intent of this loop.

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        VersionHash = (32 * VersionHash) + (int)VersionNumberStr[i] + ;
    }

    a = (VersionHash >> 24) & 0xFF;
    b = (VersionHash >> 16) & 0xFF;
    c = (VersionHash >> 8) & 0xFF;
    d = VersionHash & 0xFF;
    DecryptedVersionNumber = (0xff ^ a ^ b ^ c ^ d);

    if (EncryptedVersionNumber == DecryptedVersionNumber)
    {
        return Convert.ToUInt32(VersionHash);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

With my current understanding it bitshift 5 right and adds some value.

Also some further information:

- `encver` appears to be an encrypted version as an int (it is read from a file)
- `realver` seems to be version we are testing for match. It is looped in another function to this function from `short.MinValue` to `short.MaxValue`

What is the purpose of this loop? How does the code achieve this purpose?

Comment: This seems to be some sort of licensing scheme. Are you sure you only want to add comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop is calculating a 'hash' of the characters (digits) in the string representing the real version number. The value of VersionHash is a number which depends on every character in the string, the length of the string, and their order.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like the for loop is just part of a custom hash function - the same function that was used to generate the method param int encver, as the essence of the method is to test that the hash in encver matches a rehash of realver - presumably for some kind of integrity check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to accept your answer too but the site only lets me pick one. :(

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about the logic in this routine. This is a typical home grown encryption system to return a "hash" of the version number. I would blanket the routine in a comment that indicated the function without going into too much detail.

The for loop is generating a hash by getting the (int) value of a character in the string and then doing the equivalent of shifting it left by 4 bytes. So assuming that the (int) values of the version number are:

1, 2, 3

The for loop will generate a VersionHash of:

000200030004

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to accept your answer too but the site only lets me pick one. :(